# Bootstrapping Jersey with a filter causes Swagger to fail

Tags: jersey, swagger

In my application's `web.xml` I originally had Jersey configured as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <!-- swagger for REST API support
             codehaus for exception mappings so, for ex, POSTing malformed JSON  yields 400 bad request not 500 -->
        <param-value>com.jonarcher.rest;com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <!-- Passed thru to Swagger -->
        <param-name>api.version</param-name>
        <param-value>2.0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This seems to work just fine, and I can use the swagger-ui to browse documentation of my annotated endpoints.

However, I want to "embed" the swagger UI in my application so that the means of browsing the documentation goes along with it. I ran into problems serving the static content for swagger-ui considering the `<url-pattern>` for my Jersey servlet. Obviously I can change that to, for example, `/api/*` but that is actually not desirable in my situation.

I read [here](http://www.flamingpenguin.co.uk/blog/2010/09/02/serving-static-content-and-jersey/) that Jersey can be configured to run as a filter rather than a servlet, and then that you can specify a parameter for URLs to exclude from Jersey processing thus:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>jerseyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>.*\.html</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jerseyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

That works fine too by itself. But when I bring swagger into the mix things start to go awry. Specifically, introducing the `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` param to the filter based configuration as I had it in the servlet configuration like so:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>jerseyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>.*\.html</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.jonarcher.rest;com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jerseyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Causes the filter to fail to start, and the following error messages:

```
  SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.ApiListingResourceJSON.getAllApis(javax.servlet.ServletConfig,com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.ApiListingResourceJSON.getAllApis(javax.servlet.ServletConfig,com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo), annotated with GET of resource, class com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.ApiListingResourceJSON, is not recognized as valid resource method.
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.ApiListingResourceXML.getAllApis(javax.servlet.ServletConfig,com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.ApiListingResourceXML.getAllApis(javax.servlet.ServletConfig,com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig,javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo), annotated with GET of resource, class com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.ApiListingResourceXML, is not recognized as valid resource method.
Oct 18, 2012 11:27:30 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet initiate
SEVERE: Exception occurred when intialization
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4071)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

I got stuck at this point. Anyone have any suggestions/pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this looks like a swagger limitation. As you can see in the log messages, the problem is with injecting ServletConfig into the swagger methods. ServerConfig is only available when Jersey runs as a servlet. To make the swagger support filter as well, they would have to modify their methods to inject Jersey WebConfig class instead (which is a wrapper for FilterConfig and ServletConfig).

UPDATE: I've submitted a pull request to fix this issue in Swagger: https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/pull/64

Answer (score 0):

I'll review the pull request, but in the mean time, here's how we've solved this.

1) Deploy two different webapps, one under webapps/ROOT with the swagger UI code, the other under webapps/api with the api itself.

2) Add file handlers to use the default servlet like such:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/ui/css/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/ui/lib/*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/ui/images/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

where the ui files are under a subfolder called "ui"